# Code is messing up second row using col in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Will someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in this code? I have a contacts page that uses the same code and just loops with a query. But for some reason the second row has a huge gap as if theres something blocking it.

[image]

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Insert Loop Here --><cfoutput query="grab_contacts">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=#grab_contacts.employee_number#">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/#grab_contacts.picture#">
                            <cfif len(grab_contacts.phone_extension)>
                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension #grab_contacts.phone_extension#</div>
                            </cfif>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>#grab_contacts.firstname# #grab_contacts.lastname#</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>#grab_contacts.position#</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> #grab_contacts.department# Department<br>
                            MCTC #grab_contacts.branch# Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here --></cfoutput>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Rendered HTML

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Insert Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4854</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>IT Support Technician</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> IT Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4814</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>OPS</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> CSAD Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4856</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>David Brierton</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>IT Support Technician</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> IT Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4881</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>Associate III</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> CSAD Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4881</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>Associate I</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> CSAD Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4886</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>OPS</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Operations Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4866</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>QA Support Analyst</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> QA Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4881</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong></strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>OPS</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Desoto Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
          </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: Don't put `div` element inside of `a` elements.  That's not good practice, and I don't think it will validate the W3C Validator

Comment: @cale_b - It's valid in HTML5.

Comment: For one if you're going to nest columns you should generally use a row along with those nested columns and you aren't clearing your floats correctly. That's most likely why you're seeing this behavior in your grid. Clear the appropriate number of columns at the appropriate breakpoint. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423059/line-up-images-in-bootstrap-3-grid

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this section:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="text-center">
           <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/#grab_contacts.picture#">
             <cfif len(grab_contacts.phone_extension)>
           <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension #grab_contacts.phone_extension#</div>
             </cfif>
     </div>
</div>
```

You need to wrap new column sets in rows. You have your boxes in a row wrapper, but the content of the boxes is missing the row wrapper for your columns, so as you loop, Bootstrap is not going to apply the correct layout/positioning styles to the columns inside the boxes. Basically, just wrap your nested columns for the box content in a row class.

Answer (score 1):

You should really only have 3 'col-lg-4' inside the `.row` div which adds up to 12. Include the `<div class="row"></div>` in your loop. See snippet added (changed the `col-lg-4` to `col-xs-4` for effect)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Insert Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=266">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/amraoui_al.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4854</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Ali Amraoui</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>IT Support Technician</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> IT Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=305">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/adams_br.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4814</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Brianna Adams</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>OPS</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> CSAD Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=192">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/brierton_da.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4856</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>David Brierton</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>IT Support Technician</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> IT Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  <div class="row">
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=166">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/alicky_he.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4881</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Heather Alicky</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>Associate III</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> CSAD Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=286">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/ackles_je.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4881</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Jennifer Ackles</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>Associate I</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> CSAD Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=110">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/alfonso_ki.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4886</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Kim Alfonso</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>OPS</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Operations Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=61">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/brammer_sa.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4866</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Sara Brammer</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>QA Support Analyst</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> QA Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="contact-box">
                    <a href="../profiles/profile.cfm?employee_number=223">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" src="../images/albritton_sh.jpg">

                            <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Extension 4881</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4><strong>Shannon Albritton</strong></h4>
                        <h5>
                            <strong>OPS</strong><br><br>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Desoto Department<br>
                            MCTC Desoto Branch<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Loop Here -->
          </div>
       </div>
```

You should review the [bootstrap css page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to ensure you have the right html structure when building your grids.

Comment: How wide is the page you are looking at it in pixels? The col-lg-x class will break into individual rows at window width of 1170px.

Comment: [@David Brierton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4106374/david-brierton) Did you find a solution to your answer?